# Azure Application Gateway won't forward Error Code 500

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway

I face the issue that azure application gateway will show error 502 instead of forwarding the correct error message with HTTP code 500 from the underlying service.

Is that something one could configure? I don't want the application gateway to filter my error messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@thomasuebi, by default Azure application gateway sends out periodic probes to backend servers to check their health status. If any backend server does not respond successfully Azure application gateway marks it as unhealthy. When a client request is received for such "unhealthy" backend servers the application gateway does not forward the request to "unhealthy" backend servers and returns a "502 Bad Gateway" error to the requesting client. You can go through [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-probe-overview) documentation for additional details.
You can also go through [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/custom-error) to set custom error pages instead of 502 bad gateway page.